# Codeigniter maximum lenght for string 4096 from Model

Tags: codeigniter, model

I'm storing a JSON array in a database with using 'text' datatype column.

Storing isn't a problem but on retrieval with my Model I can only see a maximum size of 4096 characters.

How can I overcome this limitations?

Answer (score 0):

The server sets the returned output from a text field to a maximum of 4096 characters. However, you can run the MySQL query "SET TEXTSIZE #####" to set it to however many characters you want.